# Azure API Management Service not recognizing swagger

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure, swagger

I'm trying to use the Azure API Management Service.

When I go to Import API, I am currently getting the error below.

```
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Parsing error(s): Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: #. Path '', line 0, position 0.
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
API not found
```

This happens when I upload my swagger specification. This is my first time writing it, but I've looked through my document and can't seem to find any issues with it.

I've also used this document elsewhere and it worked fine.

http://pastebin.com/fb4xiuLu A link to my swagger documentation

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to upload your swagger documentation in json format.

Comment: Btw, your spec is not a valid Swagger spec. 1) Multiple types like `type: ['integer','null']` are [not supported](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/458); `type` requires a single type. 2) `null` is not a valid type because it's not [listed in the spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types). But there's a [discussion in the OpenAPI spec repo](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/229) to add "null value" support in the next version of the spec, 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

As mikalai mentioned that we need to import file with Json format. We could get more detail info about how to import API please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started#a-namecreate-api-aimport-an-api).  Get some snipped from the document.

> API Management currently supports both 1.2 and 2.0 version of Swagger document for import. Make sure that, even though [Swagger 2.0 specification](http://swagger.io/specification/) declares that host, basePath, and schemes properties are optional, your Swagger 2.0 document MUST contain those properties; otherwise it won't get imported.

Demo Swagger Json file please refer to [calapijson](http://calcapi.cloudapp.net/calcapi.json).

Comment: i don't quite understand - you mention that host basePath and schemes properties are required - but only basePath shows up in your demo file. Also I cannot find a schemes or host example in the Swagger spec. What am I missing?